# Writting Pseudocode by using package algorithmic

Tags: pseudocode, algorithmic

I have a questions, why give me a clear line at fourth line?
Can  i delete "statement" end while and end for?

```
\begin{algorithmic} [1]
\FOR{$j \gets 0$ \TO $n - 1$  } \STATE{$t \gets A[j]$ \STATE {$i\gets j-1$}
 \STATE{\WHILE{$i\geq 0$ and $A[i]>t$} \STATE{$A[i+1]\gets A[i]$\STATE{$i\gets i-1$}} \ENDWHILE $A[i+1]\gets t$}} \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misusing the tool: you shouldn't nest `\WHILE` in `\STATE` declarations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic} [1]
\FOR{$j \gets 0$ \TO $n - 1$}
  \STATE{$t \gets A[j]$}
  \STATE {$i\gets j-1$}
  \WHILE{$i\geq 0$ and $A[i]>t$}
    \STATE{$A[i+1]\gets A[i]$}
    \STATE{$i\gets i-1$}
  \ENDWHILE
  \STATE{$A[i+1]\gets t$}
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As Manuel correctly suggests in a comment, the `noend` option makes the “End” tags disappear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic} [1]
\FOR{$j \gets 0$ \TO $n - 1$}
  \STATE{$t \gets A[j]$}
  \STATE {$i\gets j-1$}
  \WHILE{$i\geq 0$ and $A[i]>t$}
    \STATE{$A[i+1]\gets A[i]$}
    \STATE{$i\gets i-1$}
  \ENDWHILE
  \STATE{$A[i+1]\gets t$}
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And with `[noend]` option to `algorithmic` package you get no **end** strings.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks, I missed that part of the question